# How do I make JSON data file objects use a layout

Tags: jekyll, liquid

First, I'm using [GitHub Pages dependencies](https://pages.github.com/versions/).

I'm trying to make use of Jekyll's data files, but I'm having problem making functional links that would use a layout to display more of the object's contents.

I can access the page via the url: `http://127.0.0.1:4000/dev/` - and my **for loop** at `./dev/index.html` shows as it should. If I click any links on that page I get a 404 message because e.g: `http://127.0.0.1:4000/dev/parent/child` couldn't be found.

The posts in Jekyll use Front Matter to determine which layout it should use, but I don't know how to make my links to use my custom layout when I click any of the links in `./dev/index.html`.

How can I create a "link" between the urls in `./dev/index.html` to display the `./_layouts/post.html`?

Here's what I got so far.

#### `./_data/dev.json`:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "I am (g)Root",
    "link": "parent",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Some kid",
        "content": "bla bla bla",
        "link": "child"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "A desk",
        "content": "texty texty",
        "link": "desk"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

#### `./dev/index.html`

```
---
layout:       page
title:        'dev'
published:    true
date:         2015-10-03 18:48:58 +02:00
category:     'module'
---

{% assign data = site.data.dev.first %}
{% for post in data.data %}
  <ul>
    <!-- URL will look like this: /parent/child -->
    <li><a href="{{ data.link | prepend: site.baseurl }}/{{ post.link }}">{{ post.name }}</a></li>
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

#### `./_layouts/post.html`

```
---
layout: default
---

{{ content }}
```

#### `./_config.yml`

```
permalink: /:categories/:title
```

Comment: Did you define the actual posts in `_posts`?

Comment: There are no posts. Only dev.json file in _data folder.

Answer (score 0):

Data files are just datas that you can consume in loops. Without a [generator plugins](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators) you're not able to generate pages from them.

In order to generate page from "datas" you can use [collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/).